# Storing long lists of card combinations in python

Tags: python

I would like to store all 5 card combinations from a 52 card deck.

An example of a hand could be: ['3s', 'Th', '4s', '9d', 'Ah']. There are approximately 2.5 million combinations of 5 cards. Some hands are better than others. I would like to rank them and then be able to look a hand up to see how good it is (i.e. hand x is in the top 10% of all hands possible).

What would be the best way to store the data?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to precompute those numbers and then just look up the category of the hand?

Comment: There's only 7462 differently ranked poker hands. You can store them in a sorted list with their accumulated frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than list all combinations, use the poker hand category (probabilities from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands)):

1. Straight flush - 0.0015%
2. Four of a kind - 0.024%
3. Full house - 0.1441%
4. Flush - 0.196%
5. Straight - 0.39%
6. Three of a kind - 2.11%
7. Two pair - 4.75%
8. One pair - 42.26%
9. High card - 50.11%

You could hold these in and look them up from a `{str:float}` dictionary, or in a `list` to use the ordering:

```
hands = ["straight flush", ...]
percs = [0.0015, ...]

better_than = sum(percs[hands.index(hand_class) + 1:])
```

Comment: Not all full houses are equal :)

Comment: Yes, but they're all better than 99.83% of all possible five-card hands!

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, what you are trying to do is probably something you ***shouldn't*** do for the particular application you are interested in, but if you insist on doing it this way (or if the parameters of your use case are not what we expect and you really do need the enumerated sequence of 52c5 combinations for some reason) you should store the set of all possible hands as a generator.  This can be easily done using itertools:

```
standard_deck = ['%i%s'%(i+1,j) for i in xrange(13) for j in 'shdc']
all_possible_five_card_hands = itertools.combinations(standard_deck,5)
```